# Use of console developer google

Tags: android, google-console-developer

Recently I came to know about console.developer.google,can anyone will tell me that what is the use of console developer google for android?

Comment: Are you seriously? Have you been banned in the Google?

Comment: Start a serious project that needs it, a tutorial will lead you to know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

It's for you to manage publication of your app.